# ¿Cómo soluciono problema con plugin php en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, vscode

Instalé un plugin en VS Code que se llama PHP Intellisense y cuando abro el Visual Studio me dice el siguiente mensaje: PHP Executable not found. install PHP 7 and add it in to your path or set the php.executablePath setting.

Como info adicional, si tengo instalado el php actualizado y uso el sistema operativo Linux Mint 19,

Recién inicio con PHP

Espero poder subsanar el error y utilizar este plugin que es de gran utilidad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer para solucionar ese problema es ir a **Settings**, escribir en la barra de búsqueda que aparece allí y colocas *Json*, en la lista te saldrá una opción que dice **Edit in settings.json** le das allí, y te aparecera un código, dónde tienes que colocar la ruta donde tienes la carpeta de `php` en mi caso la tengo en la carpeta de `wamp` y mi ruta es la siguiente:

```
"php.executablePath": "C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.2.18/php.exe", 

"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.2.18/php.exe"
```

Ese es el código que debes colocar en **settings.json**, **aviso**: tienes que colocar la ruta de la carpeta donde tenga php, sólo te estoy dando de ejemplo la ruta que yo tengo. 
Espero te sea de ayuda.

En xampp seria así:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
"php.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
```

***Editado***:
Por lo que he investigado en *Linux* para buscar la ruta de `php` en la consola se puede escribir el comando `whereis php` generalmente la ruta donde se instala `php` son: `/usr/bin/php`  ó  `usr/local/bin/php`, es cuestión de que utilices el comando para que compruebes cuál es la ruta, luego vuelves a **VSCode**

Entonces en **settings.json** la ruta debería ser algo como esto:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php",
"php.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php"
```

Comment: Está bien amigo, pero en Linux no sabrás?

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta, espero te funcione